# How do i insert bullet into nstextview automatically when user press the enter key?

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

Current now i just want make a bullet list in the nstextview,when user click enter,wrap a line,then addpen a tab and bullet automatically,any one can tell me ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the source code for TextEdit in /Developer/Examples/.

Comment: Seems that the TextEdit use the ruler to handle the textlist,but how to add textlist programmatically?